# Does the $A=bh$ formula still work even for this kind of parallelogram?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral

Usually, the formula for the area of a parallelogram is derived by cutting out a right triangle from the parallelogram and moving it to the other side of the (right) trapezoid to get a rectangle with the same base, height, and area.

However, sometimes, such a right triangle could not be cut out, particularly when the left endpoint of one of the bases of a parallelogram oriented with horizontal bases is further to the right than the right endpoint of the other base. Is it still true that $A=bh$ for such a parallelogram, where $A$, $b$, and $h$ are the area, base, and height respectively? In this case, to calculate the height, one must extend both of the bases.

Comment: The formula holds, of course, and "cutting out" the triangle is only one way to prove it among many. You could instead add up the areas of the two identical triangles sharing a diagonal, for example. You could also use the same morphing-to-rectangle "trick", but before that replicate the parallelogram $n-1$ times sideways, until the bases overlap. Then cut the triangle, calculate the area of the big rectangle, and divide by $n$.

Comment: Or extend the bases until they are vertically aligned, and then subtract the areas of the two resulting right triangles from the area of the resulting rectangle to get the area of the parallelogram.

Comment: More difficult, how to explain [parallelepiped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped)'s volume $V=Ah$ ?

Comment: If you are ok with non-right triangles, you can always cut along the line through one vertex and the midpoint of one non-adjacent edge, and rotating one of the pieces $180^\circ$ around that midpoint.